# Missing some components in SSIS toolbox in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: ssis, visual-studio-2017, sql-server-2016, toolbox

I am using `Visual Studio Community 2017` for developing SSIS packages and I use SQL Server 2016.

Some of components are not in SSIS Toolbox.

This is that I have now:

[image]

and this is my colleges have(They don't have the same version of Visual Studio that I have):

[image]

For example: I need to add a `XML Source` component to one of my `Data Flow` but there is not anymore in Other Sources sector in SSIS Toolbox.

I tried to add the missing components (Tools -> Choose Toolbox Items ->) but I don't have the tab for SSIS component.
[image]

How can I add those components (For example `XML Source`) to my Toolbox?

Answer (score 6):

I have found the cause of this problem.

By changing the `TargetServerVersion` to `SQL Server 2016` in Project properties. My project has been converted and now i have this component in my `ToolBox`.

[image]

Now, I have `XML Source` component in my SSIS ToolBox.

[image]

Comment: This leaves my toolbox completely empty, and unfortunately I cannot figure out exactly what packages/components I am missing here :(

Comment: @kadrach honestly I don't know why you have that probleme

Comment: Are you looking in the SSIS Toolbox? View > Other Windows > SSIS Toolbox @kadrach

Comment: In my case the "containers" was missing but i just had to step in the "control flow" tab an it appeared. No TeargetServer changes required

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm the answer given by Ardalan Shahgoli resolved my missing component.  I have captured a screenshot demonstrating the problem and the resolution.  In my example, I was missing a component '`Excel Source Plus`' from the '`CozyRoc`' addin

PROBLEM:

Missing some components.  The data flow has the component on the canvas, but there are of error messages in the Error List window, and you are unable to edit the component.  For example, you might see an error message such as this:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error     Validation error. Alt Data Flow_Merge Data Task: Alt Data
>   Flow_Merge Data Task: The component metadata for "Lookup Plus, clsid
>   {8DC69D45-2AD5-40C6-AAEC-25722F92D6FC}" could not be upgraded to the
>   newer version of the component. The PerformUpgrade method
>   failed.       SSASUsageStats.dtsx 0

RESOLUTION:

Changing the TargetServerVersion will effect which components are available in the 'SSIS Toolbox'.  As seen in the screenshot, there are tons more components after changing the project property TargetServerVersion.  For example, 'Excel Source Plus' is found.  The Data Flow canvas now has an image by the icon.  And the component now has an 'EDIT' option.

[image]