# Konesans Checksum for SSIS not in Toolbox

Tags: sql, ssis

I'm currently using SSIS on Visual Studio 2015 and I've installed Konesans Checksum to use.
I have installed it as admin as the installation guide suggests and apparently that's all I need to do and because i'm on SQL Server 2016, It should be added automatically to my toolbox but it isn't for some reason.

If I get a project from a colleague, it will load up with the checksum tool and I can view inside it so it is installed correctly onto my PC.

I've gone down the route of looking at Tools > Select toolbox items and searching for it but it doesn't appear.

Any help would be wonderful.

Regards,
SM

Comment: Do you have the appropriate version of the checksum? I don't know how component development works now that you can multi-target, but classically, you needed a version of your product per version of SSIS (since the interface changed with each release)

Comment: @billinkc You're correct! Turns out I was running it on Server vNext and not Server 2016.

Comment: To those still stuck here, this might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49800516/missing-some-components-in-ssis-toolbox-in-visual-studio-2017/49801705#49801705

Answer (score 0):

Verify you have the appropriate version of the checksum. I don't know how component development works now that you can multi-target, but classically, you needed a version of your product per version of SSIS (since the interface bindings changed with each release)